# Intuitive explanation for spline convolution

Tags: intuition, splines, convolution

What is spline convolution intuitively?
When should use it?
what is the motivation behind it?

Comment: Does this help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233232/the-definition-natural-cubic-splines-for-regression?  Otherwise, can you clarify what you're after?

Comment: How is your suggestion relevant to spline convolution?!

Comment: It's a definition of splines. If you need something else, please edit your question to make it clearer what you're after.