# How to get from cubic spline to natural cubic spline?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, splines

I am following a video lecture on spline regression where this formula is presented to design a cubic spline regression.

[image]

The teacher continues to explain that one would usually prefer the usage of "natural cubic splines" which add constraints that the polynomials are linear in the boundary regions.

My question: How would this formula need to change if I wanted to add these constraints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The definition of natural cubic splines for regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233232/the-definition-of-natural-cubic-splines-for-regression)

Comment: I've seen this answer before posting my question, but as I, unfortunately, don't have a math or statistics background I was not able to transfer the answer to my question of how I would need to change the equation such that it accounts for the natural spline constraints.